# python: Gui Error message

Tags: python, pyside

I try to learn GUI implementation and included my ui-file into my python script:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys
import MultiTool_widget_ui

'''class MainDialog (QDialog, MultiTool_widget_ui.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        self.setupUi(MainDialog)'''

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MultiTool_widget_ui.Ui_Form()
#w = MainDialog()
w.setupUi(QDialog)
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Executing, I get this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\jhofmann\workspace\Testumgebung\GUI.py", line 17, in
>   
>       w.setupUi(QDialog)   File "C:\Users\jhofmann\workspace\Testumgebung\MultiTool_widget_ui.py",
>   line 14, in setupUi
>       Form.setObjectName("Form") TypeError: descriptor 'setObjectName' requires a 'PySide.QtCore.QObject' object but received a 'str'

pointing to this code line in the "setupUi"-method in the ui-file:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form") <--HERE!
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.lcdNumber = QtGui.QLCDNumber(Form)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 110, 64, 23))
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 110, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
```

What could be the reason? I use Py 3.4

(The commented blocks are the ones from a tutorial video)

Comment: Please show the complete error message Traceback and indicate the line in the above code that it flagged on.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: What is the URL for the tutorial you're following?

Comment: Where is `QDialog` coming from? It seems to think it is a string. Are you fetching and instantiating it appropriately?

Comment: @GarrettHyde https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eD91nE8q8Nk

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a class object to `setupUi`, when it is expecting an *instance* of that class. Try this instead:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys
import MultiTool_widget_ui

class MainDialog (QDialog, MultiTool_widget_ui.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainDialog()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

NB: with the above multi-inheritance approach, all the widgets defined in Qt Designer end up as attributes of the top-level widget. So if you added a button in Qt Designer called `pushButton`, you can connect a slot to it like this:

```
class MainDialog (QDialog, MultiTool_widget_ui.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)

    def handleButton(self):
        print('Hello World')
```

Comment: Ok, it was missing that super. As I'm new to object oriented programming I have to learn that. In the tutorial it wasn't explained what that "super" is for so i tried it without to understand.

Comment: To understand properly, I tried to exchange the inheritance operator super but i can't comprehend where the used __init__-method is coming from because the Ui_Form-Class has no such method. So it must belong to QDialog. Please help me out here.

Comment: @Creatronik. If you **don't** override `__init__`, python will automatically call the `__init__` of all the base-classes. So when you **do** override `__init__`, you *must* explicitly perform this step yourself. Using `super` is the simplest way to do that. And in python3, it's actually even simpler, because you can just use `super().__init__()` (I used the long-hand version in my example for backwards compatibilty).

Comment: @Creatronik. Not using `super` was not the only thing wrong with your original example. You also have: `self.setupUi(MainDialog)`. Which is wrong, because it passes in the **class**, when you need to pass in an **instance** (i.e. `self`).